# Trying to write an .htaccess that rewrites URLs without redirecting

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Ok, so I've got like 6 domains for this client - all of which need to point to one main domain, for the purposes of argument, www.abc.com

However the hosting, and the account, is setup under www.xyz.com.

So basically I want to redirect all of the domains to xyz.com (which I have done), and then rewrite the URL of xyz.com to abc.com (which is on an entirely different host)

How do I do this in .htaccess?

I tried putting this into a blank file, and it just gave me a 500 internal server error:

```
RewriteCond Host: www\.abc\.com
RewriteProxy (.+) http\://www.xyz.com$1 [I,U]
```

Am I doing this right? Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 0):

Your first step should be to attack this at a DNS level.  Utilize DNS to make all the domains point to the single server that you want to handle the request.  This prevents you from needing to maintain servers that do nothing but redirect to other servers.

You can then use Apache re-directions to rewrite the domain names.

Do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.xyz\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xyz.com$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect all requests coming to the server that are not using your specified domain name to rewrite to the proper domain name.  Note the use of `R=301` flag which will indicate this is a permanent redreiction, which should help with search indexing for the domains.

Comment: And this will work even if xyz.com is only redirecting to abc.com, and not pointing to the IP of the hosting?

Comment: "The page isn't redirecting properly      
          Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: I thought you wanted to redirect to www.xyz.com from any number of other domain names? This should work on the other servers even if you don't have DNS in place (which is suggested such that you don't need to maintain a bunch of different servers or vhosts).  Can you tell me exactly what you are trying when you get that message?

Comment: The conditions above.

All I want is when I go to abc.com, the url displays as xyz.com. That is literally all I want.

Everything else is perfect.

Comment: You do realize that the request would have to be ultimately served by xyz.com server in that case right?